# Writing text in math mode

Tags: math-mode, ieee-style

I was writing an IEEE paper.I wanted to insert some texts like **IMAGE_NEW** and **IMAGE_OLD**
but when I am writing it is showing me some error.How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because the '_' is a special symbol in LaTeX, to output special symbols just place a '\' (backslash) before it. Example: IMAGE\_NEW

You could also do the following: IMAGE\textunderscore NEW